# WCF, MSMQ and independent transactions on 2 queues

Tags: wcf, transactions, msmq

I have built a WCF service that processes an MSMQ, let's call the service QueueService.  The Contract looks like this:

```
// Each call to the service will be dispatched separately, not grouped into sessions.
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class QueueServiceContract : IQueueServiceContract
{
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    public void QueueItems(List<Item> items)     // really should be called 'HandleQueueItems
    {
        //  Early in the processing I do:
        Transaction qTransaction = Transaction.Current;
        ...
        // I then check if the destination database is available.
        if(DB.IsAvailable)
            ... process the data
        else
            qTransaction.Rollback;
        ...
}
```

IQueueServiceContract looks like this:

```
// The contract will be session-less.  Each post to the queue from the client will create a single message on the queue.
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed, Namespace = "MyWebService")]
public interface IQueueServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void QueueItems(List<Item> items);
}
```

Relevant parts of the App.config for the queue service look like this.

```
<services>
  <service name="QueueService.QueueServiceContract">
    <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MyQueueServiceQueue" binding="netMsmqBinding" contract="QueueService.IQueueServiceContract">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
...
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding exactlyOnce="true" maxRetryCycles="1000" receiveRetryCount="1"
      retryCycleDelay="00:10:00" timeToLive="7.00:00:00" useActiveDirectory="false">
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>
```

This all works fine.  When the DB is not available, the Rollback causes the queue entry to be put in the retry subqueue that I have configured to retry every 10 mins for 7 days.  Everything about it works and has been in production for 6 months or so.

Now I am adding logging to the service.  The QueueService is going to queue log entries into another queue we will call: LogQueue.  The requirement is that whether the qTransaction is rolled back or not, a message should be sent to the LogQueue indicating the status of the request.

In the QueueService app.config I have added:

```
  <client>
  <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MyLogQueue"
    binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetMsmqBinding_ILogContract"
    contract="LogServiceReference.ILogContract" name="NetMsmqBinding_ILogContract">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
...
    <binding name="NetMsmqBinding_ILogContract" timeToLive="7.00:00:00">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
```

In the LogService app.config, I have:

```
    <service name="LogService.LogContract">
    <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MyLogQueue" binding="netMsmqBinding" contract="LogService.ILogContract">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
... 
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding exactlyOnce="true" maxRetryCycles="1000" receiveRetryCount="1" retryCycleDelay="00:10:00" timeToLive="7.00:00:00"  useActiveDirectory="false">
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>
...
```

Then, at the end of the QueueItems method I do the following:

```
LogContractClient proxy = new LogContractClient();
proxy.LogTransaction(myLoggingInformation);             // This queues myLoggingInformation to the LogQueue.
```

This all works fine too...  until... a database is not available and the transaction is rolled back.

The Rollback will happen before the call to proxy.LogTransaction and I will get:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while sending to the queue: The transaction specified cannot be enlisted. (-1072824232, 0xc00e0058).Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. If you are sending to a local queue, ensure the queue exists with the required access mode and authorization.'
```

If I move the proxy.LogTransaction before the qTransaction.Rollback the log entry is never put in the LogQueue.

My working theory is that WCF considers the operations on the two queues: read from QueueService queue and write to LogQueue, as a single transaction.  So, if I try to write to the LogQueue after the Rollback the transaction has already ended, but if I write to the LogQueue before calling Rollback the write to the queue is also rolled back.

Is there any way I can retain the ability to rollback the queueService transaction while not simultaneously rolling back the LogService transaction?

Comment: I would agree with your theory. Transactional consistency is being enforced against all the endpoints defined in the service. If you define the logging queue service endpoint in a separate `<service />` within your config, do you see this behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for reading and understanding the problem!  I like your thinking...  but, In the LogService there is only one endpoint.  In the QueueService I have two, but one is in the services section (to receive queued messages) and the other is in the client section (to send messages to the log).

Comment: Ok now I understand. Please see answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can fix this by wrapping the call to the log queue client in a transaction scope with TransactionScopeOption.Suppress set. This will force the action to happen outside of the ambient transaction.

Something like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope (TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
{
    // Call to enqueue log message
}
```

Your theory makes perfect sense. Because you're using transactional queues WCF is ensuring transactional consistency by enlisting everything inside the message handler in a DTC transaction. That obviously includes the enqueue of the logging message, and is expected, if unwanted, behaviour.

Comment: @shindigo glad to have helped!